# How to pass command to terraform(Azure ACI + osm tiles server)

Tags: azure, terraform, openstreetmap, azure-container-instances

I'm trying to setup overv/openstreetmap-tile-server image on Azure ACI but I have no idea how to pass command **"run"** or **"import"** to the container.

For instance if I run below terraform code:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "storage-test"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "osm-data"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "examplee" {
  name                 = "osm-tiles"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50
}


resource "azurerm_container_group" "example" {
  name                = "example-continst"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  ip_address_type     = "Public"
  dns_name_label      = "mapss11"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  restart_policy      = "Never"

  container {
    name   = "maps"
    image  = "overv/openstreetmap-tile-server"
    cpu    = "2"
    memory = "16"

    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }

    volume {
      name       = "osm-data"
      mount_path = "/data/database/"
      read_only  = false
      share_name = azurerm_storage_share.example.name

      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
      storage_account_key  = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
    }

      volume {
      name       = "osm-tiles"
      mount_path = "/data/tiles/"
      read_only  = false
      share_name = azurerm_storage_share.examplee.name

      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
      storage_account_key  = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
    }
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "testing"
  }
}
```

I can see below information:

```
usage: <import|run>
commands:
    import: Set up the database and import /data/region.osm.pbf
    run: Runs Apache and renderd to serve tiles at /tile/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
environment variables:
    THREADS: defines number of threads used for importing / tile rendering
    UPDATES: consecutive updates (enabled/disabled)
    NAME_LUA: name of .lua script to run as part of the style
    NAME_STYLE: name of the .style to use
    NAME_MML: name of the .mml file to render to mapnik.xml
    NAME_SQL: name of the .sql file to use
```

[image]

If I add **commands** section to terraform, example:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "storagetestxx"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "example" {
  name                 = "osm-data"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50
}

resource "azurerm_storage_share" "examplee" {
  name                 = "osm-tiles"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  quota                = 50
}



resource "azurerm_container_group" "example" {
  name                = "example-continst"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  ip_address_type     = "Public"
  dns_name_label      = "mapss11"
  os_type             = "Linux"
  restart_policy      = "Never"

  container {
    name   = "maps"
    image  = "overv/openstreetmap-tile-server"
    cpu    = "2"
    memory = "16"

    commands = [
      "/bin/bash", "-c", "import"
    ]

    ports {
      port     = 80
      protocol = "TCP"
    }

    volume {
      name       = "osm-data"
      mount_path = "/data/database/"
      read_only  = false
      share_name = azurerm_storage_share.example.name

      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
      storage_account_key  = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
    }

      volume {
      name       = "osm-tiles"
      mount_path = "/data/tiles/"
      read_only  = false
      share_name = azurerm_storage_share.examplee.name

      storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
      storage_account_key  = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
    }
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "testing"
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
/bin/bash: line 1: import: command not found
```

[image]

Below you can find how it looks like with pure docker:

```
docker run \
    -v osm-data:/data/database/ \
    -v osm-tiles:/data/tiles/ \
    overv/openstreetmap-tile-server \
    import
```

Documentation:

- [azurerm_container_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_group#environment_variables)
- [openstreetmap-tile-server](https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server)

@update:
I've changed command to + added some env variables:

```
   commands = [
      "import"
    ]

  environment_variables = {
      DOWNLOAD_PBF="https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/luxembourg-latest.osm.pbf"
      DOWNLOAD_POLY="https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/luxembourg.poly"
    }
```

and now I'm getting:

```
Error: Failed to start container maps, Error response: to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: failed to create container 106a87f1f61033aa11ddeee2c0f6b5797157545516e1f55009c34d72ce9b50cf: guest RPC failure: failed to create container: failed to run runc create/exec call for container 106a87f1f61033aa11ddeee2c0f6b5797157545516e1f55009c34d72ce9b50cf with exit status 1: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "run": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do:

```
commands = ["import"]
```

If you look at the `overv/openstreetmap-tile-server` image's [Dockerfile](https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server/blob/master/Dockerfile) you'll find that it has entrypoint `/run.sh`. [This script](https://github.com/Overv/openstreetmap-tile-server/blob/master/run.sh) in turn has the following code:

```
if [ "$1" == "import" ]; then
  # ...
fi
```

So `import` is not a shell command, it's a `/run.sh` command.